# Download the file to external storage folder using download manager

Tags: android, storage

I need to download the file and them modify it.
So i've been trying to download it to Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS but then due to new requirements of Google i can't access it from Android 11 even with `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=”true”` flag: https://medium.com/swlh/sample-for-android-storage-access-framework-aka-scoped-storage-for-basic-use-cases-3ee4fee404fc

I need to download it to granted directory
So, generally we ask the user a permission for specific folders using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` intent action, available on Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher, allows users to select a specific directory, granting your app access to all of the files and sub-directories within that directory, and keeps the uri for this directory. Something like (if we get path from uri) `"/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myFolder"`.

```
val asdPermissionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        startActivityForResult(asdPermissionIntent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (data != null) {
                //this is the uri user has provided us
                val treeUri: Uri? = data.data
                val appFolderPath = treeUri.toString()
                // Save url for future
                playerViewModel.updateAppFolderPath(appFolderPath)

                val baseDocumentTreeUri = Objects.requireNonNull(treeUri) ?: return
                val takeFlags =
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                // take persistable Uri Permission for future use
                context?.contentResolver?.takePersistableUriPermission(
                    baseDocumentTreeUri,
                    takeFlags
                )

 
            }
        }
    }
```

After the user granted permission we can read/write to this directory. Is there any way to download the file with `DownloadManager` to this directory.

I use download manager in this manner.

```
    val path = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myFolder"
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setTitle(fileName)
            .setDescription(desc)
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, fileName)
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
        val downloadManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager?
        val downloadID =
            downloadManager!!.enqueue(request) // enqueue puts the download request in the queue.
```

And i got the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories: /storage/emulated/0/Download/myfolder
```

How to download the file to granted directory?

Comment: `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path,` You should specify only one public folder. Not a complete full path.

Answer (score 0):

> > i've been trying to download it to Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD

That is no storage location but only a folder name. In this case 'Download'.

You do not need any permission to let DownloadManager download a file to for instance the Download directory on external storage.

Once the file is downloaded your app can obtain an uri from DownloadManager for the downloaded file to read or edit the beast.

Comment: Yes, of course i can downlod to Download folder. But how can i access this folder ? I need an `“WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` permission. To do : `context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` Which would not work  because One of the requirements for Api level 29 was usage of Android Storage Access Framework (SAF) instead of just getting a “WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” permission. And from api 31 i can't use workaround `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=”true”` flag.

Comment: All nonsense. You do not need access to that folder. You need access to that file. Which you will have if you request the DownloadManager an uri for that file.

Comment: But i would need to change the extension of this file. Is it possible to do it without SAF?

Comment: Try an update() for the obtained uri.

Comment: Btw do you know the way to get `FileInputStream` from uri? I can get only `InputStream`.

Comment: InputStream will do. What do you need more? Code to read from it is the same.

Comment: I just converted downloaded file from some format to h264 video then i need to transform it to mv4.
I found some custom solution with `FileChanell` as input data.

Comment: i can simply use ffmpeg to convert it  but i am not sure that i can do it with downloaded file.

Comment: UPD: We can get `chanel` doing this.

 
       `FileInputStream(applicationContext.contentResolver.openFile(uri,"r",null)?.fileDescriptor).channel`

Comment: Btw what do you mean by "Try an update() for the obtained uri"? is there a way to change file extension with ASF?

Comment: contentResolver.update,(uri, contentvalues,..) with in contentvalues a new .DISPLAY_NAME. You can change display name and hence extension. But from Android 11 not all extensions are allowed in all directories.

Comment: Yeah, in this way: 
     values.put( "_display_name", "myvideo.mv4")
        applicationContext.contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null), but sems does not work.